# Passar valores do Banco de dados para o Spinner

Tags: android, json, spinners

Estou buscando valores dos clientes no banco de dados através do PHP/MYSQL e estou retornando via JSON, e gostaria de passar para o SPINNER mais de 1 argumento (idcliente + nomecliente)... No caso, eu consegui fazer rodar o SPINNER passando o "nomecliente" que aparece para ser selecionado... Como faço pra passar o "idcliente" também... No caso, gostaria de substituir a ID da SPINNER pela "idcliente"... Segue abaixo o código que faço o retorno do JSON, incluindo no Adapter...

Segue abaixo o código editado com as modificações, código completo.

Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente {

private int mId;
private String mNome;

public Cliente(int id, String nome) {
    mId = id;
    mNome = nome;
}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public String getNome() {
    return mNome;
}
```

}

Classe de Registro

```
public class RegistrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView botaoVoltar;
private Button botaoRegistrar;
private EditText textoCPF, textoEmail;
private Spinner spinnerCliente;
private Cliente cliente;
private String idcliente;
private ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
private RequestQueue requestQueue, requestQueue2;
private static final String URL = "http://www.caixinhadosmotoristas.com.br/spinner-cliente.php";
private static final String URLReg = "http://www.caixinhadosmotoristas.com.br/validacao.php?acao=register";
private StringRequest request, request2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar);

    botaoVoltar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.botaoVoltarId);
    botaoRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoRegistrarId);
    textoCPF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoCpfId);
    textoEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoEmailId);
    spinnerCliente = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerClienteId);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    RetornaJSONClientes();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCliente.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinnerCliente.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            cliente = (Cliente) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            idcliente = "1";
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            cliente = null;
        }
    });

    SimpleMaskFormatter mascaraCPF = new SimpleMaskFormatter("NNN.NNN.NNN-NN");
    MaskTextWatcher maskCPF = new MaskTextWatcher(textoCPF, mascaraCPF);
    textoCPF.addTextChangedListener(maskCPF);

    botaoRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            request2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLReg, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("200")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("mensagem"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("mensagem"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    idcliente = "" + cliente.getId();
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("idcliente", idcliente);
                    hashMap.put("nome", cliente.getNome());
                    hashMap.put("cpf2", textoCPF.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("email", textoEmail.getText().toString());
                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue2.add(request2);
        }
    });

    botaoVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent voltaLogin = new Intent(RegistrarActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(voltaLogin);
        }
    });
}

private void RetornaJSONClientes(){
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            String jsonString;
            int jsonInt;

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    jsonString = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome");
                    jsonInt = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idcliente");

                    clientes.add(new Cliente(jsonInt, jsonString));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

Comment: Olá, reverti a sua última edição pois a dúvida anterior já estava solucionada e você adicionou uma dúvida nova. Não tem problema criar mais perguntas, mas para isso clique em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask e coloque sua nova dúvida lá. Considere esse tópico como encerrado e considere aceitar a resposta que mais lhe ajudou. Veja mais aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma classe `Cliente`, com as variáveis `id` e `nome` e vá guardando os dados do json num `ArrayList<Cliente>`

Ex:

```
public class Cliente {

    private int mId;
    private String mName;

    public Cliente(int id, String name) {
        mId = id;
        mName = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }   
}

ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
clientes.add(new Cliente(1, "Fulano 1"));
clientes.add(new Cliente(2, "Fulano 2"));
```

Ao criar o adapter do Spinner, associe com o ArrayList acima. Ex:

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, clientes);
```

Para acessar um cliente do Spinner:

```
Cliente cliente;
Spinner spinner; // Inicialize com o findViewById, setAdapter, etc


spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        cliente = (Cliente) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        cliente = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Fiz as modificações que você colocou ai em cima, e ta dando errado ainda, o spinner inicializa normalmente, só que os dados passados pra ele, está com o "link" todo... Vou colocar uma imagem no final da pergunta pra você vê como está...

Comment: Falha minha. Editei minha resposta. Faltou criar um método toString() na classe que guarda os dados para definir o que vai aparecer no spinner.

Comment: Meu camarada, deu certinho agora, só mais uma ajuda, no caso do meu código acima, ao clicar no botão registrar, eu envio os dados através de um HashMap<String, String>, como eu faria pra enviar o idcliente também, que no caso é "int"... Tem como você me ajudar nesse detalhe?  Vou editar a pergunta com o código atualizado.

Comment: Sugiro que você volte a pergunta como estava e crie uma nova, pois a sua dúvida anterior poderia ajudar outras pessoas. Do jeito que está agora, parece que minha resposta não tem sentido para a pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, beleza vou fazer uma nova pergunta, desculpa ai, é que sou novo por aqui, to pegando o jeito ainda.. rs!

Comment: Sem stress. Estamos aí para ajudar (quando dá, rs)

Comment: Marcio, você pode me ajudar com essa dúvida aqui? To batendo cabeça e tá complicado, to te enviando o link da pergunta... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223970/enviando-dados-para-banco-mysql-com-php